# Apply filter using AngularJS that eliminates some options in array

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, filter, splice

My e-commerce site sends back all options for USPS and UPS shipping + rates via an API. These are all the options a customer sees at checkout:

- US Postal Ground $XX.XX
- USPS Priority Mail Express 1-Day™ $XX.XX
- UPS Ground $XX.XX
- UPS 3 Day Select $XX.XX
- UPS 2nd Day Air $XX.XX
- UPS Next Day Air $XX.XX

Now my client wants me to remove all options except US Postal Ground and UPS Ground. I want to create a filter to do this and apply the filter to my dropdown options.

html:

```
<div ng-show="user.ShipMethod != null && shippers" ng-class="{'view-form-select': !currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName, '': currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName }">
    <label ng-class="{required: !currentOrder.IsMultipleShip() && user.ShipMethod != null}" ng-show="currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName || !currentOrder.IsMultipleShip() && user.ShipMethod != null">{{('Shipping' | r) + ' Method' | xlat}}</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-change="updateShipper()" name="shipMethod" ng-model="currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName" ng-show="user.ShipMethod.ShipperSelectionType == 'UserDropDown'" ng-options="shipper.Name as ((shipper.Name | USPSFilter) + ' ' + (shipper.ShippingRate.Price | currency | xlat)) for shipper in shippers" ng-required="!currentOrder.IsMultipleShip() && user.ShipMethod != null" >
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I tried creating a filter and using the `splice` method but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]